# Laravel 5 Using guzzle to scrape data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to scrape data from https://beta.tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/oldham-central-tram and insert it into my page.

This is my first time doing it and I got completely stuck:

Route::

```
Route::get('hello', 'GuzzleController@guzzle');
```

Controller::

```
function guzzle(){
$client = new Client();
$results = $client->get('https://beta.tfgm.com/public-transport/tram/stops/oldham-central-tram');
return $response->getBody();
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: maybe use `return $results->getBody()` instead of `$response->getBody()`?

Comment: how would I display that data in blade template engine?

Comment: you could pass it as a variable. `return view('guzzle')->with('results', $results);`

Comment: oh okay and how do I use it in the view? foreach with $result as $result?

Comment: it really depends on what kind of data you receive, if its an array do a foreach. if its a single string or object, access it statically. more information can be found over here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade

Comment: well have a look at that link and advice me please, I want to basically scrape travel information from that page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145457/discussion-between-imatwar-and-przemek).

Comment: Consider using this package instead: https://github.com/kitetail/zttp - Zttp is a simple Guzzle wrapper designed to provide a really pleasant development experience for most common use cases.